# How to save image which is not uploaded to the database in MVC?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

Every question on this site, every tutorial which I found is about saving uploaded an image in database using `HttpPostedFileBase`. Instead of this:

```
<input type='file'>
```

I have this in my `Registration.cshtml`:

```
<div id="copiedimage">
    <img class="default-avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar.png")" alt='default-avatar' />
</div>
```

This `div` contains `img` which will maybe be changed. It will be more clear to understand from the picture:[image]

So, this left circle avatar is actually `img` from this `div`. Default image on page load is from the `Url.Content`, but this image will be changed if user clicks on an image from the slider, or if he chooses his own picture(horse) and clicks on it.

I have `UserAvatar` model:

```
public class UserAvatar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public byte[] Avatar { get; set; }
}
```

The view includes the following html for the 'default' avatar and the slider

```
<div id="copiedimage"> 
    <img class="default-avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar.png")" alt='default-avatar' /> 
</div>
<div class="slider"> 
    <img class="avatar selected" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar.png")" alt='avatar' /> 
    <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_dog.png")" alt='dog' /> 
    <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_chihuahua.png")" alt='chihuahua' />
    .... // more images 
</div>
```

The script to set assign the selected avatar is

```
$('.avatar').click(function () { 
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected'); 
    $(this).addClass('selected'); 
    var selectedAvatar = $('.avatar.selected')[0]; 
    var defaultAvatar = $('#copiedimage img')[0]; 
    defaultAvatar.src = selectedAvatar.src; 
    defaultAvatar.alt = selectedAvatar.alt; 
});
```

How can I pass this image to `Controller` in `MVC`? How can I save that image to the SQL database?

Comment: Why do you have a `byte[] Avatar` property. It seems all you want to do is post back the url of the selected image (e.g. Content/Images/Account/xxx.png`) which you could store in a hidden input when the image is selected

Comment: I want to save this image to the database, so I read that the byte[ ] is the best way to save the image...

Comment: Why? Its already saved in your `Content/Images/Account` folder. Saving it again is pointless extra overhead. All you need to do is save the path/file name

Comment: So, I should create something like this... If user select image which already exist in the Content/Image/ folder (from this slider), I should save only path/file name, and if user select image which he uploaded from his local machine, I should use HttpPostedFileBase?

Comment: Yes (and if the user uploaded their own, you would save it to a folder and just store the path/filename in the db)

Comment: Thank you very much, it is clear now. ;-)

Comment: Hello @StephenMuecke, I am not sure how to store url in some hidden input when the image is selected... Can you put some code please? I am begginer in asp.net...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167622/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-nemanja).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point storing the byte array of the image in the database since its already stored as a file in your folder (although you could do it using the `File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);` method)

Instead store the path of the file in the database, and you model will now be

```
public class UserAvatar
{
    ....
    public string AvatarPath { get; set; }
}
```

In the GET method, pass and instance of `UserAvatar`, which you can set to the 'default' ("/Content/Images/Account/avatar.png") for a new item, or to the existing value if editing.

Then in the view, include a hidden input for the `AvatarPath` path property which will be updated if the user selects an image from your slider

```
<div id="copiedimage"> 
    <img class="default-avatar" src="@Model.AvatarPath" /> // bind to the model
</div>
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AvatarPath)
```

and modify the script to

```
$('.avatar').click(function () { 
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected'); 
    $(this).addClass('selected'); 
    var selectedAvatar = $('.avatar.selected')[0]; 
    var defaultAvatar = $('#copiedimage img')[0]; 
    defaultAvatar.src = selectedAvatar.src; 
    defaultAvatar.alt = selectedAvatar.alt;
    $('#AvatarPath').val(selectedAvatar.src); // set the value of the hidden input
});
```

When you submit your form, say to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UserAvatar model)
```

the model will be correctly bound with the selected image path (or the default if the user did not select an image)